# Maven surefire plugin junit parallel execution

Tags: maven, maven-3, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

How could we know if maven surefire plugin has executed Junits in parallel? Is there any build log mentioning it etc?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: Maven docs including above URL has been checked and found that this is not specified.